# Insertable view with NOT EXISTS clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW autors_view 
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM autors a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'ExID' 
                   FROM `exercises` 
                   WHERE `exercises`.AutorID = a.AutorID) 
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Now I'd like to have this view insertable. Sadly if I add a value using INSERT I get an error that the view is not insertable. According to the doc this is because I use a.AutorID in the WHERE clause.

The view should select all authors that have no entry in exercises and it should be insertable (as a new author never has an exercise this should work). Is there a way to do so?

Thank you and greetings

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking - although it seems as though you might be going about it (whatever it is) the wrong way

Comment: Nope. As stated in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html), a view cannot be insertable if it utilizes a subquery that uses fields in the table being inserted to. you'd have to use a trigger to check for collisions instead.

Comment: This is part of an exercise. I have a table exercise and a table autor. The entries in exercise reference the table autor. The question is now to create an insertable view that lists all autors that have no exercise.

Comment: I think this was an error in the exercise. It says "create an updateable view" that .... (test it with an update and insert statement)". Thats the same as the exercise before where it was insertable. I guess that was just a typo, it should just be updateable and that already works!